# After hide one row list then face issue to apply different color to list row by its position

Tags: android, listview

I hide one list item from listview adapter now i try to apply two different color to Android listview item by list position, at that time I faced problem that two row color is same due to hide one row.This is my code for hiding row and apply color to row.

```
String Name=stationlist.get(position).getStation_name();
 //hide one repeated row
    if(Name.equals("Old High Court Interchange")) {
        if (flag == true) {
            holder.mainll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isHiddenInterchange=1;
            flag = false;
        }else{
            holder.mainll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }else{
        holder.mainll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flag= true;

    }

 private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30FFFFFF, 0x30A9A9A9 };//For apply two different color to row.
 int colorPos = position % colors.length;
 holder.mainll.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
```

[image: Here I attached image so you can get idea]

Comment: If `isHiddenInterchange` default is 0, then change `int colorPos = position % colors.length;` to `int colorPos = (position + isHiddenInterchange) % colors.length;` Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only hiding the list item. You are not deleting the item from list itself. 
This is just a simple hack to get what you want.

```
color_position = position;
String Name=stationlist.get(position).getStation_name();

//hide one repeated row

if(Name.equals("Old High Court Interchange")) {

    holder.mainll.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    color_postion += 1
}else{

    holder.mainll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**But, correct implementation is handling this in your activity itself , not the adapter.**

In your activity, check if list contains "Old High Court Interchange", and if it does ,remove it(you can make a copy of the list before doing this) and then call notifyDataSetChanged()